# Difference between sales of 2 rows with filter Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working on Power BI and have a table like this:

```
Date    Sales    Colour
1/2/20    10    Red
1/2/20    15    Blue
2/2/20    50    Red
2/2/20    8     Blue
```

I would like to add a new difference column which gives the difference between blue and red sales per day like this:

```
Date    Sales    Colour    Diff
1/2/20    10    Red        5
1/2/20    15    Blue       5
2/2/20    50    Red        -42
2/2/20    8     Blue       -42
```

Been trying to use Calulate with filters but I'm stuck trying to get the right result if someone could help provide a solution please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
VAR Sales=SUM('YourTableName'[Sales])
VAR Colour = SelectedValue('YourTableName'[Colour],"Selected more then 1 color")
VAR OtherSales = 
        Calculate(
            SUM('YourTableName'[Sales])
            ,'YourTableName'[Colour] <> Colour
        )
VAR Diff= Sales-OtherSales
VAR Result = 
            IF(CountRows(Values('YourTableName'))>1
                ,Colour
                ,Diff
            )

RETURN Result
```

Or

```
VAR Colour = SelectedValue('YourTableName'[Colour],"Selected more then 1 color")

VAR ColorSales = 
      Calculate(
         SUM('YourTableName'[Sales])
         ,'YourTableName'[Colour] = Colour
      )

VAR OtherSales = 
        Calculate(
            SUM('YourTableName'[Sales])
            ,'YourTableName'[Colour] <> Colour
        )
VAR Diff= ColorSales-OtherSales
VAR Result = 
            IF(CountRows(Values('YourTableName'))>1
                ,Colour
                ,Diff
            )

RETURN Result
```